# magento2 add display default value for column on admin grid

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

I have created a custom module to display the sale product details.
The columns are as follow, Product_id, name, quantity and Status.
I got the output.

My question is,
I need to display completed order details by default but now it's displaying the pending order details by default.

Could anyone give me suggestions to sort it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the output,

In my xml that defines the grid, I replaced Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid as Test\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Custom

In my Grid.php

```
    namespace Test\Custom\Block\Adminhtml\Custom;
    use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid as WidgetGrid;
    class Grid extends WidgetGrid
    {
        protected function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
            $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);        
            //for default filter
            if ($this->hasData('default_filter')){
                $this->setDefaultFilter($this->getData('default_filter'));
            }
        }
        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
            //on clicking reset filter on Grid it will make 'complete' status as default:
            if(!$this->getParam($this->getVarNameFilter(), null)) {
                $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('salesGrid.status', array('eq' => 'complete'));
                $data['status'] = 'complete';           
                $this->_setFilterValues($data);
            }
            parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your collections according to your requirement. Make collections filtered by order status complete.

Comment: Could you please find my updated question in http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135084/prepared-filter-for-admin-grid-magento2

Comment: I need to have default sorted filter on my collection